# I need for loop to return random int that is never the same

Tags: php

```
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++){
    rand(0,$count);
}
```

How can i make this for loop return random INT from 0 to $count, but each time it loops it never return the same result.

Like if $count is 5 it will generate 4,1,0,2,3.

Comment: The `$count` can take any value? If it will always be a prime number, you can write your own http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator.

Comment: Create an array with value from 0 to $count (using `range`), shuffle that array, and then `shift` the first item from that array each time you need a new, unique random value. (If you need to do this more times than the array actually contains items, so more than $count + 1 times, then you need to start the process with a fresh array again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't really mean "never", but simply never within your scope of your loop

```
$count = 5;
$values = range(0, $count-1);
shuffle($values);
foreach($values as $value) {
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 4;
$r     = range(0, $count-1);
shuffle($r);
print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there are more efficient solutions. But if need to use `rand()` then try this.

```
<?php

$count = 5;
$arr = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < $count;) {
    $val = rand(0, $count);
    if (!in_array($val, $arr)) {
        $arr[] = $val;
        $x++;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
?>
```